# Fastest way to add a field to a large table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a fairly large table (approx 400 million rows) and I need to add new column of type bit with NOT NULL constraint. My approach is to add the field without NOT NULL constraint, set the field to 0 and the alter the column to add the NOT NULL constraint.
This is a pretty slow process. Is there a quicker approach?

I am on SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645215/how-do-i-add-a-column-to-large-sql-server-table

Comment: SQL Server 2014 Enterprise

Comment: Question is 7 years old and clearly there are new possibilities now

Comment: @johnmcp Yes, that question is a bit old and none of the answers reflected the new info. I have corrected that ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you are on Enterprise Edition and version >= 2012 then the information in [Online non-NULL with values column add in SQL Server 2012](http://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/online-non-null-with-values-column-add-in-sql-server-11/) should apply.

```
Alter table yourtable 
    add newcolumn bit not null default 0;
```

Should be metadata only and, unlike your proposed solution, will not have to write anything to all rows.

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @johnmcp and Martin: The `WITH VALUES` clause is not needed here. That is only for adding a NULLable column that has a default and you want the initial value to be the default instead of `NULL`. For this particular case, only the `DEFAULT` is needed (and set to `0` instead of `1` ;).

Comment: @johnmcp So the answer to this question was the same answer to the question that was 9 years old?

Comment: @dfundako nope. The online default values was only introduced in 2012. It wasn't mentioned in that other question until srutzky gave an answer just now.